# SAS: What's the optimal way to find the sum of a column by another column?

Tags: algorithm, sas

I want to find out the best way to perform a group-by in SAS so I can perform some benchmarks. The simplest two ways I can think of is `Proc SQL` and `Proc means`. Here is the example in `proc sql`

`proc sql noprint; /* took 6 mins */
    create table summ as select
            id,
            sum(val)
        from 
            randint
        group by 
            id
        ;
    quit;`

I think there are ways to make this run fast

- use `sasfile` command to load the data into memory first
- create an index on `id`

Are there any other options I can use? Any SAS options I should turn on to make this run as fast as possible? I am not tied to proc sql nor proc means, so if there are faster ways then I would love to know about it!!!

My set up code is as below

```
options macrogen;
options obs=max sortsize=max source2 FULLSTIMER;
options minoperator SASTRACE=',,,d' SASTRACELOC=SASLOG;
options compress = binary NOSTSUFFIX;
options noxwait noxsync;
options LRECL=32767;

proc fcmp outlib=work.myfunc.sample;
    function RandBetween(min, max);
        return (min + floor((1 + max - min) * rand("uniform")));
    endsub;
run;

options cmplib=work.myfunc;

data RandInt;
    do i = 1 to 250000000;
        id = RandBetween(1, 2500000);
        val = rand("uniform");
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

My SAS comparison macros are as below

```
%macro sasbench(dosql = N); %macro _; %mend;
    %if &dosql. = Y %then %do;
        proc sql noprint; /* took 6 mins */
            create table summ as select
                id,
                sum(val)
            from 
                randint
            group by 
                id
            ;
        quit;
    %end;

    proc means data=randint  sum noprint;
        var val ;
        class id;
        output out = summmeans(drop=_type_ _freq_) sum = /autoname;
    run;
%mend;

%sasbench();
/**/
/*sasfile randint load;*/
/*%sasbench();*/
/*sasfile randint close;*/

proc datasets lib=work;
    modify randint;
    INDEX CREATE id / nomiss;
run;

%sasbench();
```

Answer (score 2):

`sasfile` is only a benefit if the entire data set can fit into session ram limits and if the data set is going to be used more than once.  I suppose this would make sense if your benchmark includes multiple runs / different techniques on the same sasfile.

An index on id would help if the data was unsorted by id.  When the data set is presorted by id the id column metadata will have sortedby flag set which a procedure can use for its own internal optimization, however there is no guarantee.  As for indexes, use `option msglevel=i` to get informational messages in the log about index selection during processing.

The fastest way is direct addressing, but requires enough ram to handle the largest id value as an array index:

- `array ids(250000000) _temporary_`
- `ids(id) + value`

The next fastest way is probably hand coded array based hashing:

- search SAS conference proceedings for papers by Paul Dorfman

The next fastest hash way is probably the hash component object with key suminc.

**DATA Step was edited to align with the comments**

```
data demo_data;
  do rownum = 1 to 1000;
    id = ceil(100*ranuni(123));     * NOTE: 100 different groups, disordered;
    value = ceil(1000*ranuni(123)); * NOTE: want to sum value over group, for demonstration individual values integers from 1..1000;
    output;
  end;
run;

data _null_;
  if 0 then set demo_data(keep=id value);                         %* prep pdv ;
  length total 8;                                                 %* prep keysum variable ;
  call missing (total);                                           %* prevent warnings ;
  declare hash ids (ordered:'a', suminc:'value', keysum:'total'); %* ordered ensures keys will be sorted ascending upon output ;
  ids.defineKey('id');
 *ids.defineData('id');                                           % * not having a defineData is an implicit way of adding only the keys as data, only data + keysum variables are .output;
  ids.defineDone();

  * read all records and touch each hash key in order to perform tacit total+value summation;
  do until (end);
    set demo_data end=end;
    if ids.find() ne 0 then ids.add();
  end;

  ids.output(dataset:'sum_value_over_id'); * save the summation of each key combination;
  stop;
run;
```

Note: There can be only one keysum variable.

If the suminc variable was set to be always 1 instead of value, then the keysum would be the count instead of the total.

Obtaining both sum and count over group via hash would require an explicit defineData for a count and sum variable and slightly different statements, such as:

```
declare hash ids (ordered:'a');
...
ids.defineData('id', 'count', 'total');
...
    if ids.find() ne 0 then do; count=0; total=0; end;
    count+1;
    total+value;
    ids.replace();
...
```

However, if value is known to be always a natural number, and group size is known to be < 10<sup>group size limit</sup> you could numerically encode the count by using a suminc of `value + 10`<sup>-group size limit</sup> and numerically decode count by processing the output data with `count = (total - int(total)) * 10`<sup>group size limit</sup>.

For sorted data the fastest way is most likely a DOW loop with accumulation.

```
proc sort data=foo;
  by id;
data sum_value_over_id_v2(keep=id total);
  do until (last.id);
    set foo; 
    by id;
    total = sum(total, value);
  end;
run;
```

You will likely find that I/O is largest component of performance.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand how an index would work here.  It's likely an index wouldn't do a thing in this case (I ran the test code and it does absolutely nothing); and it's unlikely it makes a difference sorted or unsorted, unless there's something more than just a sum here.  I agree with some of what you have up here, though I think I disagree with the ordering necessarily, and it's really too general.

Comment: Also a slight modification suggested: instead of using `hiter` to output, use the `output` hash object method.

Comment: @Joe can you show an example of what u mean by output hash object?

Comment: Joe:  thanks for improvement.  I forgot that the keysum variable is output along  with the hash data.  Xia:  ids.output(dataset:'work.ids_hash_data') will create a SAS data set from the contents of the hash object.  The columns will be those listed in the <hash>.DefineData(...) and the KeySum: variable.  For the cases of .DefineDone() being called without a prior .DefineData() the keys are tacitly made data fields in the hash.

Comment: @Richard you might want to update your answer, but I am making these changes 1) data _null_ 2) comment out hiter and do ids.output instead

Answer (score 1):

The best answer varies dramatically by the application.  In your example, `PROC SQL` at least on my machine significantly outperforms `PROC MEANS`, but there are plenty of cases where it will not do so.  It's able to in this case because it's building hash tables behind the scenes, more than likely, which are quite fast - a single pass through the data is all that's needed.

You certainly could speed things up by putting your full dataset into memory with SASFILE, if you have room to store the whole thing.  You would have to have it in memory to *begin* with, though, more than likely; just reading it into memory for this purpose alone wouldn't really help since you're doing that read anyway.

As Richard notes, there are a bunch of ways to do this.  I think `PROC SQL` will often be the fastest or similar to the fastest in simple cases, both because it's multithreaded (as opposed to data step being single threaded) and because it's got a fast hash table backend.

`PROC MEANS` is also usually going to be competitive, the case you show in the example is almost a worst case for it since it's got a huge number of class variables so I think it may be creating a temporary table on disk.  It's also multithreaded. Reduce the class variable categories to 2500 instead of 2,500,000 and you get `PROC MEANS` a bit faster than `PROC SQL` (but within the margin of error).

Data step accumulation, either in a hash table or a DoW loop, will sometimes outperform both of the above, and sometimes not, again depending on the data.  Here it does outperform slightly.  The code for data step accumulation tends to be a bit more complex, which is why I'd usually discourage it unless the savings is substantial (having more code to maintain is worse, typically).  `PROC MEANS` and `PROC SQL` require less maintenance and less to understand.  But in applications where performance is critical and these solutions happen to be superior, it may be worth it to go this route, especially if the data step is helpful.  Of course, the hash table method is limited to fitting the results in memory, though usually that's manageable.

---

Ultimately, I would encourage you to use whatever method is easiest to maintain but still gives sufficient performance; and when possible try to be self consistent with other code.  If most of your code is in SQL, that is probably fine.  SASFILE and indexes probably won't be needed, unless you're doing more complicated things than you present above.  Summation is actually more work than I/O in many cases.  Don't overcomplicate it, ultimately: programmer hours and difficulty of QA is something that should trump basic performance, unless you're talking several hours' difference.  And if you are, then just run tests on your actual use case and see what works best.

Comment: good advice. The purpose is to find the fastest method in SAS and benchmark it against other systems e.g. Spark, R, Julia, Pandas etc.

Comment: Well, good luck.  Those systems aren't particularly comparable to SAS except in very rough concepts; in particular, they're mostly in-memory processors. So I think you'd have a hard time benchmarking them all in a consistent way that actually described real use cases.  I'd really hope that something beyond "how fast does it sum a column" would be the determining factor in what you used of that list.

Comment: I am certified to advance level in SAS as well and I have already made the move to Julia/R.

Comment: Basically, I am writing a package in Julia & R that process the data in chunks like SAS, starting from "cold" i.e. have a large dataset sitting at rest on the hard drive not in memory. Guess what? I can process the same amount of data in 1/3 of the time. So this exercise is me trying to boil down the benchmarks to the most basic tasks and show that other can outperform SAS in like-for-like tasks; but I do want to get the best possible code for SAS so that I can show SAS is slow not because I haven't optimised it to the nth degree.

Comment: You're still not comparing anything that's particularly relevant.  SAS isn't the fastest system out there, because it's not designed to be: it's a 4GL, not a lower level language.  You're saying, which is better, SQL or Javascript?  The answer is, it depends on what you're doing.  It's trivial to find something that processes sums faster than SAS because SAS is happy to process them at a sufficient speed, not in some optimized bytecode.  SAS's strengths are in abstracting things, and in robust and simple statistical procedure implementations.

Comment: If direct speed is important to you, then test the code and data you'd actually use.  (And make sure your package is as thoroughly tested and supported as SAS is ...)   There are so many different results just from the above three tests depending on the exact scenario of how many class values, how many rows, etc., and how your SAS system is set up (what kind of disk read buffers it has for example), that it's useless to benchmark anything other than what you're actually doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158918/discussion-between-xiaodai-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the data is sorted then this is another solution

```
data sum_value_over_id_v2(keep=id total);
    set a.randint(keep=id val); 
    by id;  
    total + val;  
    if last.id then do;
        output;
        total = 0;
    end;
    drop val;
run;
```